# Is it possible to upload text files (e.g. JSON) to wordpress blog in any way?

Tags: uploads

I want to show some code but it needs to be in a raw format, is it possible to upload a simple text file? I'm aware of the file type restrictions but if there is a nifty trick to do this it would be great.

Comment: Upload text files and do what with them? In a test, the media uploader just uploaded a `.txt` without complaint, by the way.

Comment: I'm using yourname.wordpress.com (because I'm too cheap to afford hosting). Is it actually possible to access ftp on this? I've tried uploading a .txt file using the media uploader, didn't work for me.

Comment: wordpress.com questions are off topic per the [faq](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

```
function upload_file($file_url) {
    if ( ! filter_var($file_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ) return false;
    $get = wp_remote_get( $file_url );
    if ( ! is_wp_error(  $get ) ) {
      // check mime type if you want
      // $mime_type = wp_remote_retrieve_header( $get, 'content-type' );     
      return wp_upload_bits( basename($file_url), '', wp_remote_retrieve_body( $get ) );
    }
    return false;
}

// use it like
upload_file('http://www.site.com/path/myfile.json');
```

For what is returned see [wp_upload_bits](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_bits) in codex.